# I want to group by my data with date and time In postgres SQL and want one row of each groupby column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to fetch data from history table and I want to group by `usergroupid` and I want only one row of usergroupid 237935 and 761793 out of multiple rows.

I get this error

> Column "history.entrytime" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

This is my query:

```
SELECT  
    TO_CHAR(entrytime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI'), usergroupid 
FROM 
    "public"."history" 
WHERE 
    deviceid = 17355763  usergroupid IN (237935,761793) 
GROUP BY 
    TO_CHAR(entrytime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI'), usergroupid 
ORDER BY
    entrytime DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I want following output:

| to_char | usergroupid |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-19 02:04:10 | 237935 |
| 2022-11-19 02:05:40 | 761793 |

This is my demo table:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your data as formatted text into your request instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you simply want the maximum entrytime per usergroupid. In order to get one row per usergroupid, you `GROUP BY usergroupid`. In order to get the maximum entrytime, you select `MAX(entrytime)`.

```
SELECT  MAX(entrytime), usergroupid
FROM public.history
WHERE deviceid = 17355763 AND usergroupid IN (237935,761793) 
GROUP BY usergroupid
ORDER BY usergroupid;
```